# Time complexity of this adjacency list-based algorithm which finds the common edges of two undirected graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, adjacency-list

The problem asks for creating the adjacency list of a graph which contains only the edges that are present in both graphs (they have the same number of vertices).
I have come up with this algorithm written in pseudocode for which I cannot determine the time complexity (best case, worst case). After thinking a lot, I believe I cannot even say which is the best case or the worst case.

```
for i <- 1,v do
    for v in adj1[i] do
        found <- false
        for u in adj2[i] do
            if (u=v) then
                found = true
                break
            endif
        endfor
        if (found) then
            adj_int[i].push_back(v)
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm?
Let V=number of vertices, E1=number of edges from graph1 and E2=number of edges from graph2.

Comment: I assume you mean "undirected" and not "unidirected"?

Comment: PS We typically don't care about "best case". Only "worst case compelxity" and "average complexity"

Comment: @Stef indeed, my bad, it was a typo. I also said about the best case because I have encountered it many times since I started learning algorithmics